# Long running process using TPL. Could not find how to write callback?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, callback, task-parallel-library, long-running-processes

I have used TPL to do long running process like generating 1,00,000 PDF in my asp.net application. Codes is like bellow:

```
private Task<ErrorList> GeneratePDF()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(

        --pdf generation goes here....
    )
}
```

Can anybody please help me to do following action:

1. I want to intimate UI how many PDF has been generated till now.
2. Once process is completed i want to show one popup page with all details of PDF generation. I could not find a way to write callback....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are best off using an architecture that polls your web page/service for the progress and status.
[How To: Submit and Poll for Long-Running Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650675.aspx) is one starting point.

Here's another: [Asynchronous processing in ASP.Net MVC with Ajax progress bar](http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2009/11/15/asynchronous-processing-in-asp-net-mvc-with-ajax-progress-bar.aspx)

For TPL related callback/progress reporting, see: [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)